# Q: Typescript: TS7006: Parameter implicity has any type

Tags: node.js, typescript

TS7006: Parameter 'port' implicitly has an 'any' type.
`constructor(port) {`

TS7006: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
`Emit(message) {`

I'm at loss here because every other answer is to add type "any" or whatever.
In this case both port and message DO have a type, number and string respectively.
note that i don't usually work with node/typescript, so i have no clue if the config is good. Also setting strict: false and noImplicitAny: false yields similar error with Emit()

`throw new TypeError(${relative(cwd, fileName)}: Emit skipped);`

Also this errors come from .js files, so i guess tsc passes?

```
export class EventEmitter {
    private port: number

    constructor(port: number) {
        this.port = port
        ...
    }

    public Emit(message: string) {
        this.io.send(message)
    }
```

package.json scripts

```
"start": "cd dashboard && (npm run dev > dashboard.log 2>&1 &) && cd .. && tsc-watch --onSuccess \"npm run watch\"",
"watch": "nodemon --watch './src/*.ts' --exec 'node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm' src/main.ts",
```

ignore dashboard part, its some svelte frontend part that needs to be run by side.

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "include": [
        "src",
        "dashboard/src/**/*.d.ts",
        "dashboard/src/**/*.js",
        "dashboard/src/**/*.ts",
        "dashboard/src/**/*.svelte"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es2018",
        "module": "esnext",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "src/*",
                "node_modules/*"
            ]
        },
        "esModuleInterop": true,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer was to set `checkJS: false` and `allowJS: false`
If this is wrong and someone knows anything better, let me know.
thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).